# Need optimization for a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

Please help me on optimization for a query below:

```
select s.ZahialgaID, sum(s.Quantity) total_qty, MAX(s.date_moved) MaxDate
from
    tCardMoveForTailan s
where
    (
        s.date_moved is null or
        s.date_moved <= @date_end or
        convert(varchar(20), s.date_moved, 111) = convert(varchar(20), @date_end, 111)
    ) and
    (
        s.TsehID = GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode('nyrav') or
        s.TsehID = GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode('rejected') or
        s.TsehID = GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode('orooson') or
        s.TsehID = GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode('zereg')
    )
group by s.ZahialgaID;
```

Use this data for your query:
http://orion.mn/updateapp/data_to_play.rar

Now this query runs for 10 seconds on 200000 rows.
But I guess that 1 or 2 seconds is possible for such a simple query. Please help me on this task!

The table tCardMoveForTailan has a clustered index as below:

```
create clustered index IX_tCardMoveForTailan_2 on tCardMoveForTailan (ZahialgaID, TsehID, date_moved);
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

As requested by comments, the body of dbo.GetTsehByCode() function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTsehByCode (@code nvarchar(50))  
RETURNS int AS  
BEGIN
    declare @tsehid int
    select @tsehid = TsehID from tTseh where code=@code
    RETURN @tsehid
END
```

The table tTseh has only 10 rows.

Comment: I think the bottleneck is the function `GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode()`, which gets called for each and every row. Can you post it's code? Perhaps it can be rewritten as a table valued function.

Comment: it is probably the UDFs (GoyoMSDB.dbo.GetTsehByCode) try commenting them one by one and check the performance but I can't get this condition: 's.date_moved <= @ date_end or
        convert(varchar(20), s.date_moved, 111) = convert(varchar(20), @ date_end, 111)' it looks senseless to me you are already comparing the values as dates why converting them

Comment: `GetTsehByCode` seems like it should be replaced with a lookup table, but I really can't be sure unless you post that function as well.

Comment: You guys are great. It was the function GetTsehByCode(). When I replace it by its return value, the query takes less than a second. Thanks guys

Comment: Please consider answering your own question and accept the answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
;with cte as (
    select TsehID from tTseh where code In ( 'nyrav','rejected','orooson','zereg' )
)
select 
    s.ZahialgaID, 
    sum(s.Quantity) total_qty, 
    MAX(s.date_moved) MaxDate
from
    tCardMoveForTailan s
    inner join cte on ( s.TsehID = cte.TsehID )
where
    ( s.date_moved is null )
    or ( s.date_moved <= @date_end )
    or ( convert(varchar(20), s.date_moved, 111) = convert(varchar(20), @date_end, 111) )
group by s.ZahialgaID;
```